# Nested curly braces/data bindings

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I am using Angular2 for my app. In my html I have a *ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array">
   {{element.id}}
</div>
```

Then I have an array of objects like this:

```
someData: [{element.id: 511}, {element.id : 123}] 
//Just some data in the values, nothing special
```

What I need is now to nest those two data-bindings and I actually couldn't find any good advice.

What I want is something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array">
      {{element.id}}
   <p>{{someData[{{element.id}}]}} </p>
</div>
```

So my question is whether this is even possible and how. Or, if you have any advice to achieve the same thing in a different way, I'd love to hear that, too. 
The only thing is, that I can't change any of my arrays, as I need the "element.id" property in "someData" to know wich values go with another. 
Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the inner `{{}}` and all should be fine.

Everything inside `{{}}` is interpreted as expression, there is just no need to add `{{}}` inside another pair and it's also invalid.

Comment: `someData` is also an array.. So it will need loop

Comment: Loop to achieve what? If you want to loop, you can add `*ngFor` to `<p>`.

Comment: This is actually not working, as someData[element.id] doesn't display anything. I don't know if I've been clear enough.. Every element.id is a property of someData and I want to display every single value. I guess it's something more like {{someData[X].(element.id)}}, if you know what I want to say.

Comment: I don't know what you expect `{{}}` to do. `{{}}` just executes the code inside it and converts the result of the code to a string. `{{}}` doesn't do any looping or similar.

Comment: According to your explanation about what you try to accomplish, just removing the inner `{{}}` should do what you want. `someData[X].(element.id)` doesn't make much sense. What would `X` be and `.(` would be try to access a nameless property that had to be a function, which can't exist).

Comment: I am very new to programming, so my expectations are quite limited. :D From my understanding by now I feel like @Poonam is right, I need to loop through someData as well, as every object with a element.id property is a single element within it. I rebuild my someData a bit, so that it is a single object having every element.id as a property and now it does  work as I wanted.